# NSRegularExpression to remove the rest codes

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I want to remove the all strings from the below html after some parts.

```
<br>
<br>
</div>
<div class="notation_notes">
<hr>
<br>
●表記について<br>
<ul>
    <li>このファイルは W3C 勧告 XHTML1.1 にそった形式で作成されています。</li>
    <li>［＃…］は、入力者による注を表す記号です。</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="card" style="display: block; ">
<hr>
<br>
<a href="JavaScript:goLibCard();" id="goAZLibCard">●図書カード</a><script type="text/javascript" src="../../contents.js"></script>
```

I would like to remove all codes after this tag.

```
  <div class="notation_notes">
```

My codes is here, but it doesn't change anything as result.  Could anyone help me to fix this?

```
NSArray *regExPatternList = @[@"<div class=\"notation_notes\">(.*)"];


NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExPattern
                                                                        options:0
                                                                          error:nil];

html = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:html
                                        options:0
                                          range:NSMakeRange(0,html.length)
                                   withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: What is it returning? If the html is all one line it looks like it should return the tag + everything following the tag.

Comment: This regex doesn't change anything as result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion regex is not the weapon of choice for what it is you want to achieve. Simply search for the `<div class="notation_notes">` string with the NSString `rangeOfString` method. Then extract the part of the string you want to get with `substringWithRange`. It is simpler and incidentally performs a lot better too.

The reason why your regex is not working is probably because you have not used the `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` as a regex option when compiling your pattern. The dot in your `(.*)` will not match new lines without it.